# Can't get pjax to work on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pjax

I'm trying to get [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/) to work on a Rails app but none of the links are being annotated with pjax. I think pjax isn't really being loaded. I'm using pjax_rails and am basically following the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax) instructions but using `//= require jquery.pjax` instead of just `pjax`. I'm also using it with bootstrap which *may* cause an issue but I'm not sure. My other thought is that is that the pjax javascript isn't being loaded and I need to run something like `$('a').pjax('[data-pjax-container]')`

To be clear the main problem is that pjax isn't being loaded client side and thus when I make requests the X-PJAX header is not being set.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. First problem was that the unbeknownst to me the assests pipeline was turned off so the pjax javascript file wasn't being included. Instead I went with the pjax rack gem and dumped it into the public directory. Then I created a new javascript file with `$('a').pjax('[data-pjax-container]')` and it works! Although I'm not sure why I need to manually call that javascript when all the documentation seems to point to the fact that it should be already there.